# When to name a converter in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've been working with converters in my PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu objects. They work fine if I only tell which class the converter is referring to:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = DescriptorVO.class)
public class DescriptorVOConverter implements Converter { ... }
```

This way, I don't have to explicitly tell the JSF component which converter should be used when it is populated with objects of class `DescriptorVO`.

However, I made a page that used a `p:SelectManyCheckbox` and I couldn't for the life of me know why it wasn't calling my converter. Then I gave it a name, like so:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = RoleVO.class, value = "roleVOConverter")
public class RoleVOConverter implements Converter { ... }
```

and passed it as one of the component's properties

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="cbx_roles" required="true" converter="roleVOConverter"
    requiredMessage="At least one role must be selected."
    value="#{userView.selectedRoles}" layout="responsive">
    <f:selectItems value="#{userView.roles}" var="role"
        itemLabel="#{role.title}" itemValue="#{role}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

and *voi la*, it started calling the converter correctly. This raised a question to me regarding when I should name my converters (through the `value` attribute) and when telling them which class the converter should be used with (with the `forClass` attribute) is enough. I never had to namy any converters when working with PrimeFaces, only for this particular `SelectManyCheckbox` component. Do different components have different necessities regarding converters or did I just get the concept of converters wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen when the `value` of the `UISelectMany` component references a generic `java.util.Collection` type like `List<Role>` instead of an array like `Role[]`. This is specified in [javadoc of `UISelectMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) (emphasis mine):

> Obtain the `Converter` using the following algorithm:
>
> - If the component has an attached `Converter`, use it.
> - If not, look for a `ValueExpression` for value (if any). The `ValueExpression` must point to something that is:
>
>   - An array of primitives (such as `int[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for this primitive type.
>   - An array of objects (such as `Integer[]` or `String[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for the underlying element type.
>   - **A `java.util.Collection`. Do not convert the values.**
> - If for any reason a `Converter` cannot be found, assume the type to be a `String` array.

The reason is, the generic type `<Role>` is lost during runtime and not directly determinable. It works when you're using [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org) instead of [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) as it will in case of a `java.util.Collection` inspect the actual type by manually iterating over `<f:selectItem(s)>` and determine the `Converter` based on first non-`null` value.

I created spec [issue 1422](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1422) on this to get this in JSF spec and improve Mojarra too.

#### See also:

- [UISelectMany on a List<T> causes java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872633/uiselectmany-on-a-listt-causes-java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string/)
- [Why does JSF put String values in a Map<..., Integer>? And how to work around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842652/why-does-jsf-put-string-values-in-a-map-integer-and-how-to-work-around-it/)
- [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/use-enum-in-hselectmanycheckbox)

Comment: That's exactly what happens with me. I forgot to mention the `ClassCastException`, but that happened too: I was getting `String` representations of my objects inside my `ArrayList<RoleVO>`. And you say this behavior is in the documentation of the `javax.faces` API and yet MyFaces has overriden it?

Comment: That's correct. MyFaces often goes steps further to improve behavior where it "doesn't make sense".