# Is a value put to viewScope map in EL without explicit converting always cast to java.lang.String?

Tags: jsf, el

The value in `f:selectItem` is an Integer (`Const.DB_NEW_DATASET`) but the output of `testlistener` is always `java.lang.String`. That's not what I had expected.

xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:importConstants type="foo.bar.Const" />
</f:metadata>
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{viewScope.foo}">
    <f:selectItem
        itemValue="#{Const.DB_NEW_DATASET}"
        itemLabel="foo" />
    <f:selectItem
        itemValue="#{Const.DB_NEW_DATASET}"
        itemLabel="bar" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.testlistener}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    @ViewMap
    private Map<String, Object> viewMap;

    public void testlistener() {
        System.out.println(viewMap.get('foo').getClass());
    }
}


public class Const {
    public static final Integer DB_NEW_DATASET = -1;
}
```

Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not "cast to `java.lang.String`" at all. It's just the default type of [`ServletRequest#getParameter()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) which is then left unconverted by JSF.

This is because the [`ValueExpression#getType()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/3.0/apidocs/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#getType-javax.el.ELContext-) of `#{viewScope.foo}` returns `java.lang.Object` and thus JSF won't perform any automatic conversion against any registered `@FacesConverter(forClass)`.

You need to explicitly specify the built-in [`javax.faces.Integer`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/apidocs/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html) converter which is essentially a `@FacesConverter(forClass=java.lang.Integer)`.

```
<h:selectOneListbox ... converterId="javax.faces.Integer">
```

This is not necessary if you're using e.g. `#{bean.foo}` with a `private Integer foo`, because this way the `ValueExpression#getType()` will return `java.lang.Integer` and thus JSF can find the built-in converter.

#### See also:

- [Why does JSF put String values in a Map<..., Integer>? And how to work around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842652/why-does-jsf-put-string-values-in-a-map-integer-and-how-to-work-around-it/)
- [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter' - Why do I need a Converter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter)